# Select2 Plugin Jquery , issues with default message

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am Using the select2 plugin to display auto suggested drop downs and tags.

Below is how my code looks :

```
$('.select2Member').select2({       
        multiple: true,
         minimumInputLength :1,
        placeholder : cake.message.notice.b,
        ajax {
         url ": cake.url.a ,
        dataType : json,
        quietMillis : 100,
       cache : true,
        data :function(term,page){
           return{
           term: term,
            page_limit : 10
           };

         }
        } 
    });
```

Everything seems to be working fine except when the field is empty .It's only then that the drop down message appears saying 'No matches found'.

I want to remove the default message when the field is empty .

I have tried adding the below paramenters to Jquery:

```
tags:[''],
tokenSeparators: [','],
formatNoMatches: function() {
            return '';
        },
dropdownCssClass: 'select2-hidden'
```

Also added a class select2-hidden with display:none !important attribute.

In the above case , it gets hidden , but even if there is a successful search it doesn't show.

Any expert advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Use proper tags, I've edited them. This has *nothing* to do with CakePHP, nor with php at all!

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net